# Can I use jquery doucument ready in a loaded html / script subpage

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

I am using a dynamic sequence of multiple forms. Each form (a subpage) is dynamically loaded in the main page with $( "#dyn-form" ).load( form-x.html ). 
Each form-x.html has its own script embedded. This script must execute after the form-x.html has been loaded. 
I start each script with a document ready, to make sure the  dynamically loaded content is loaded in the dom. Does this make sense?

UPDATE

Thanks for all your help. I was able to solve it just by calling the embedded function of the loaded page.html in the load callback : window[page].apply();

```
function nextForm(page) {
    $("#dyn-form").load(page + '.html', function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
            var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
            $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
        else {          // load OK and finished then call embedded script
            window[page].apply();
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    nextForm('form-1');     // load the first form  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute some scripts after loading the remote page,you can do like this

```
$("#dyn-form" ).load("form-x.html",function(){
  //Script here will execute only after the load completed
});
```

Comment: The first part isn't true. **The DOM ready event fires only once!**

Comment: If the dom ready fires only once, how can I trigger the script in my form-x.html. Can I use .on (to bind the event to a function) and .trigger to execute the user event? I trigger the event in the load callback.